# Firebase Crashlytics: Upload dSYMs show warning & Firebase console show dSYM required (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

I have uploaded dSYMs to Firebase with `upload-symbols` command which is downloaded from AppStore Connect. Most of the dSYMs is uploaded successfully but it shows warnings for few dSYMs. Bitcode is enabled in my app & using 'DWARF with dSYM File' for 'Debug information format' in build settings.

I am getting the following warning for a few dSYMs:

```
warning: Crashlytics found a dSYM with hidden symbols at path: /Users/name/Downloads/appDsyms/c362ba63-3100-3a48-9040-72af1fe519e3.dSYM. This will result in hidden stack frames for that library in Crashlytics. This can occur if you have  bitcode enabled in your app. If you have chosen to upload the symbols for your app to Apple, make sure to download the symbolicated dSYMs from Apple through Xcode or iTunes Connect. If you have chosen NOT to upload symbols to Apple, you can deobfuscate your dSYMs manually with the BCSymbolMaps found within the archive of your application using the following command: dsymutil --symbol-map <BCSymbolFile> <dSYMFileWithHiddenSymbols>.This will perform an in-place deobfuscation of the provided dSYM.To silence this warning, pass the --skip-dsym-validation flag to upload-symbols / run.
```

Used command for uploading dSYMs:

```
/ProjectPath/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp /ProjectPath/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /DsymsPath/appDsyms
```

Firebase console is showing dSYM required:
[Firebase console is showing dSYM required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dry3v.png)

Answer (score 1):

1. In archive file you will find folder "BCSymbolMaps", copy it anywhere
2. Copy your c362ba63-3100-3a48-9040-72af1fe519e3.**dSYM** to c362ba63-3100-3a48-9040-72af1fe519e3.**zip**.
3. In this zip file you will find file **\Content\Resources\c362ba63-3100-3a48-9040-72af1fe519e3.plist**
4. In this file you need key "**DBGOriginalUUID**". This key is file name for needed from BCSymbolMaps folder. (Let it be XXXXXXX. So you need find file XXXXXXX.bcsymbolmap in folder BCSymbolMaps which we got from xcarchive.)
5. Now we have everything for decoding our dSYM file. Just run next
   dsymutil --symbol-map /Users/name/Downloads/appDsyms/XXXXXXX.bcsymbolmap  /Users/name/Downloads/appDsyms/c362ba63-3100-3a48-9040-72af1fe519e3.dSYM
6. Now you can repeat sending dSYMs to server.